# How to implement this function declaration or function expression with arrow function?

Tags: javascript

```
<p class="qn"><a href="#"> Question:What is JavaScript?</a></p>
    <p class="answ ">
      JavaScript is a lightweight, interpreted programming language with
      object-oriented capabilities that allows you to build interactivity into
      otherwise static HTML pages. The general-purpose core of the language has
      been embedded in Netscape, Internet Explorer, and other web browsers.
    </p>
    <p class="qn">
      <span> Question:</span> What are the data types supported by JavaScript?
    </p>
    <p class="answ ">
      The data types supported by JavaScript are: Undefined Null Boolean String
      Symbol Number Object
    </p>
    <p class="qn">
      <span> Question:</span> What is the purpose of ‘This’ operator in
      JavaScript?
    </p>
    <p class="answ ">
      The JavaScript this keyword refers to the object it belongs to. This has
      different values depending on where it is used. In a method, this refers
      to the owner object and in a function, this refers to the global object.
    </p>

.qn {
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orangered;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.qn::after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.qn.active::after {
  content: "-";
}
.qn.active + .answ {
  display: block;
}

.answ {
  display: none;
}

const qn = document.querySelectorAll(".qn");
const answ = document.querySelectorAll(".answ");
```

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION DECLARATION

```
// for (let i = 0; i < qn.length; i++) {
//   qn[i].addEventListener("click", showAnswer);

//   function showAnswer() {
//     qn[i].classList.toggle("active");
//   }
// }
```

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
FUNCTION EXPRESSION

```
for (let i = 0; i < qn.length; i++) {
  qn[i].addEventListener("click", function showAnswer() {
    qn[i].classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
```

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
//ARROW FUNCTION
??????
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

How to implement this function expression or function declaration
with arrow function.

```js
const qn = document.querySelectorAll(".qn");
const answ = document.querySelectorAll(".answ");

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//FUNCTION EXPRESSION

for (let i = 0; i < qn.length; i++) {
  qn[i].addEventListener("click", function showAnswer() {
    qn[i].classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
//ARROW FUNCTION

//for (let i = 0; i < qn.length; i++) {
 // qn[i].addEventListener("click", function showAnswer() {
 //   qn[i].classList.toggle("active");
 // });
//}                   
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// BOTH FUNCTION EXPRESSION AND ARROW FUNCTION WORKS WHAT I NEED TO KNOW IS HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS
// WITH ARROW FUNCTION

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//ARROW FUNCTION

//???????????????????                  
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
p.answ {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
}

.qn {
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orangered;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.qn::after {
  content: "+";
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.qn.active::after {
  content: "-";
}
.qn.active + .answ {
  display: block;
}

.answ {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <script src="jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p class="qn"><a href="#"> Question:What is JavaScript?</a></p>
    <p class="answ">
      JavaScript is a lightweight, interpreted programming language with
      object-oriented capabilities that allows you to build interactivity into
      otherwise static HTML pages. The general-purpose core of the language has
      been embedded in Netscape, Internet Explorer, and other web browsers.
    </p>
    <p class="qn">
      <span> Question:</span> What are the data types supported by JavaScript?
    </p>
    <p class="answ">
      The data types supported by JavaScript are: Undefined Null Boolean String
      Symbol Number Object
    </p>
    <p class="qn">
      <span> Question:</span> What is the purpose of ‘This’ operator in
      JavaScript?
    </p>
    <p class="answ">
      The JavaScript this keyword refers to the object it belongs to. This has
      different values depending on where it is used. In a method, this refers
      to the owner object and in a function, this refers to the global object.
    </p>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <p></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

function expression and function declaration is working. How to implement this code using Arrow function? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Function declarations are function-scoped and hoisted, not block-scoped, so you can't do it with function declarations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
for (let i = 0; i < qn.length; i++) {
  qn[i].addEventListener("click", () => qn[i].classList.toggle("active"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < qn.length; i++) {
      qn[i].onclick =()=>{
        qn[i].classList.toggle("active");
      }
```

[on click] can take part in [addEventListener("click")]
and your arrow function

Comment: `addEventListener()` is generally considered preferable to `onXXX`. It's more general and has more flexible options.